# how to insert Personalization element inside another Personalization in exacttarget

Tags: exacttarget, ampscript

I am working on exact target to trigger email template to customers.

let say i have one Personalization element **%%url_A%%** and this **url_A** contains html another Personalization element **%%url_B%%**

Example:

Template: `<table><tr><td>%%url_A%%</td><tr></table>`

**url_A**  : Hi, Welcome to our services to proceed further please clink on this url: `<a href=%%url_B%%></a>`

**url_B**  : http://www.example.com

so using exact target i am able to replace **%%url_A%%** in html template but **url_B** not replacing.

Please suggest an answer to resolve this issue.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. will post now

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to this:
You can use dynamic content blocks in your email and apply rules in order to fetch the required content.
Here, as your url_A seems to contain only static data, you can hard code it as follows:
%%[
VAR url_B
SET url_B = ''
]%%

Hi, Welcome to our services to proceed further please clink on this url: